# mapbox.js 3.3.0 — How to add "max" et "min" zoom

Tags: javascript, dictionary, zooming, mapbox

I would like to add a "min-zoom" and "max-zoom" to my map builded with mapbox.js 3.3.0 (and not Mapbox-GL-JS).

My code is the same than the official example of the API: https://jsfiddle.net/omgjtnkx/.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoianVsZXN2YXVsb250IiwiYSI6ImNrN2NnY2VybTBuNngzbG56Y3Nzeno0czUifQ.dGyxSFyanB-Kbit0wvsZCQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([40, -74.50], 9)
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the API documentation for the [`Map` class](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.3.0/l-map-class/), you can add `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options upon `Map` initialization. That is, something like:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = '* YOUR MAPBOX ACCESS TOKEN HERE */;
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 16
  })
  .setView([40, -74.50], 9)
  .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));
```